# persons.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I am trying to make a filter search. I am calling the function using

```
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      {
        persons.map((persons) => <Persons persons={persons} setFilter= {setFilter} key={persons.id} />)
      }
    </div>
```

so I created an array using `map` however when I pass it through

```
  const Persons = ({ persons, setFilter }) => {
    const checkPersonsName = setFilter === '' ? 
      persons
    :
      persons.filter((person) => person.name.toLowerCase().includes(setFilter) )
    return (<li>{checkPersonsName.name} {checkPersonsName.number}</li>)

  }
```

it gives me an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: persons.filter is not a function.

I did a `console.log` and persons should be an array. so I am not quite sure what to do here and why I am getting this error.

Comment: you have variable name conflict, try writing it like this persons.map(person => <Component persons={persons} /> )

Answer (score 0):

As far as I concern, you are using persons two times unnecessarily. You first map throught the array `persons` and then use the same `persons` as a prop of the component `Persons`.

I think that it'd be better if you use `Persons` as a function, not as a React component, and insert your `map` and `li` rendering after the `filter`. Check my codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-ives-rmyymq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thanks. thats what i ended up doing after i realized my naming conflict